# Why I am finding this difference implementing the "Sending a Simple Message" official WSO2 ESB tutorial?

Tags: middleware, wso2, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2 ESB** and I have a doubt following this simple official tutorial related to **sending a simple message**:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message

I have installed the **ESB Server** and the provided **Eclipse Tooling** version and I started with the tutorial but I am noting a difference between what I obtain and what is shown in the previous tutorial.

The "problem" happens in the **Connecting to the back-end service** section of this tutorial (near the beginning).

The tutorial starts creating a new **ESB Solution Project** that creates these 4 projects in my workspace:

[image]

then there is the **Connecting to the back-end service** section where a new endpoint is setted on the **SampleServices** project.

Ok, afther that this operation is done, on the tutorial is shown this immage:

[image]

As you can see there is a **SampleApp** that wrap my **SampleServices** project.

The "problem" is that, after that I do this operation, I have the **endpoint** setted but I don't have any **SampleApp** wrapping my **SampleServices**, this is what I have in my **package exlporer**:

[image]

As you can see there is no **SampleApp** wrapper. Why this difference from the tutorial? I have followed it step by step.

What is the problem? What am I missing? May it compromise the final result?

Comment: The wrapper is actually a Maven Multi Module Project. It should be created as step one - and then you would create the ESB Solution Project inside it. It is not obligatory - it is convenient, though, for organisation purposes.